# Why is there an error here; Unity 2D Animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and I made some sort of mistake here and I was wondering what I could do to fix it?

This is what it says at the bottom of my screen in unity:

Assets/Scripts/Movement.cs(59,18): error CS1061: Type `Animator' does not contain a definition for` setFloat' and no extension method `setFloat' of type` Animator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MathExtensions;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Movement")]
[SerializeField] private float walkSpeed = 3.0f;
[SerializeField] private float sprintSpeed = 6.0f;
[SerializeField] private float animationWalkSpeed = 1.5f;

[Header("Jumping")]
[SerializeField] private int numberOfJumps = 1;
[SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 10.0f;
[SerializeField] private Transform isGroundedTransform;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask floorLayer;
[SerializeField] private float isGroundedRadius;
// how many seconds the player counts as being grounded even when not
[SerializeField] private float rememberBeingGroundedTime = 0.1f;
[SerializeField] private GameObject jumpImagesParent;
[SerializeField] private float fallMultiplier = 2.5f;
[SerializeField] private float lowJumpMultiplier = 2.0f;
[Header("Knockback")]
[SerializeField] float knockbackDuration = 0.2f;
[SerializeField] float knockbackPower = 100f;

public Animator animator;

#region Private Variables
private Rigidbody2D _rigidBody;
private bool _isGrounded;
private int _additionalJumps;
private float _lastTimeGrounded;

private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;
private Animator _spriteAnimator;
private Image[] _jumpSpriteRenderers;
#endregion

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    if (_rigidBody == null) Debug.Log("No rigidbody2D component attached");
    _spriteRenderer = transform.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    _spriteAnimator = transform.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

    SetupJumpSprites();
    PlayerMovementState.Instance.CanMove = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    animator.setFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));  

    if (CanMove(horizontal))
    {
        Move(horizontal);
    }
    else if (_spriteAnimator.GetBool("isRunning"))
    {
        _spriteAnimator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && CanJump())
    {
        Jump();
    }
    if (!_isGrounded)
    {
        BetterJump();
    }
    CheckIfGrounded();

}
```

the error is at line 59, where it says animator.setFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));

I'm new to stack overflow and coding so could anyone help me out?

Comment: Methods in Unity API as in general per `c#` convention start with an upper case letter ... it is [`Animator.SetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetFloat.html)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

replace `setFloat` with `SetFloat`

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)